Suddenly no longer getting proper transactionIdentifier with StoreKit
Since a few days I noticed that my in-app purchase flow seems to be broken. The restored transactionID is always a single number that starts at 0 and increments. Usually each transaction is a very large unique number, but somehow this is not the case here. I haven't changed anything in my code which is as follows:
func purchaseProduct(_ product: Product, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        let payment = SKPayment(product: product.skProduct)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
        purchaseStatus = .pending
        purchaseCompletion = completion
    }

func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        for transaction in transactions {
            print(transaction)
            switch transaction.transactionState {
            case .purchased:
                print(transaction.transactionIdentifier) // this is not proper
               
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.purchaseStatus = .success
                }
                resetPurchaseStatus()
            case .failed:
                // Handle failed purchase
                if let error = transaction.error {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.purchaseStatus = .failure(error)
                    }
                }
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
                resetPurchaseStatus()
            case .restored:
                // Handle restored purchases
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.purchaseStatus = .success
                }
                resetPurchaseStatus()
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }

Anyone ever experience this?

If an original transaction is present then you might be able to read the transaction identifier from this instead. Try using transaction.original?.transactionIdentifier ?? transaction.transactionIdentifier

I did but there is never an original... I believe I've narrowed down the issue to the presence of a StoreKit file that contains my products. I tried deleting that file but I'm getting error after error as well. No idea how to solve this mess.

The original store kit is being deprecated unless you have a really good reason to support older versions you should switch to StoreKit 2

Thanks, I'll refactor to migrate to StoreKit2!

In this particular case it seems to have been an issue with having a StoreKit file associated with my debug configuration. This results in transaction IDs being generated sequentially (starting at 0). Removing the file, thus switching back to the proper sandbox environment, seems to have fixed the problem.
